# DSE Analytics in Cluster Configuration

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

Previously we had three nodes cluster with two Cassandra nodes datacenter in one dc and one spark enabled node in different dc. 
Spark was running smoothly in that configurations.
Then we tried adding another node in analytics dc with spark enabled. We had configured GossipingPropertyFileSnitch as well as added seeds.
But now when we start the cluster, spark master is assigned to both the nodes separately.  So spark job still runs on a single node. What configurations are we missing regarding running spark job in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't make an adjustments in the Analytics keyspace replication, or didn't run the repair after you added a node.  Please refer to [instructions in official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/analytics/settingReplFactorAnalyticsKeyspaces.html).

Also, please check that you configured the same DC for both of Analytics nodes, because the Spark master is elected per DC.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the issue. Port was blocked on both systems. Thank you for your prompt reply.